Bull queue to call multiple queues inside in synchronous manner
I have two queues: one for registration and another for commission. I want to complete the registration queue first, then use the updated user data to start the commission queue, all within a single transaction. I need to ensure that only one transaction is processed at a time.
Here’s my code:
const transactionQueue = new Queue('transactionQueue', {
    limiter: {
        max: 1,
        duration: 1000 
    }
});

async function processRegistration(parentId, userId) {
    logger.info(`Adding registration job for user ${userId}`);
    try {
        const job = await registrationQueue.add({ parentId, userId });
        const result = await job.finished();
        logger.info(`Registration job completed for user ${userId}`);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(`Registration job failed for user ${userId}: ${err.message}`);
        throw err;
    }
}

async function processCommission(user, points) {
    logger.info(`Adding commission job for user ${user.userId}`);
    try {
        const job = await commissionQueue.add({ user, points });
        const result = await job.finished();
        logger.info(`Commission job completed for user ${user.userId}`);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(`Commission job failed for user ${user.userId}: ${err.message}`);
        throw err;
    }
}

transactionQueue.process(async (job) => {
    const { orderId, status, userId } = job.data;
    const session = await mongoose.startSession();

    try {
        await session.withTransaction(async () => {
            const order = await Order.findById(orderId).populate('products').session(session);
            if (!order) {
                throw new Error(`Order ${orderId} not found`);
            }

            const statusMap = {
                0: 'Pending',
                1: 'Shipped',
                2: 'Delivered',
                3: 'Cancelled'
            };

            if (order.status === statusMap[status]) {
                logger.info(`Order ${orderId} is already in the desired status: ${statusMap[status]}`);
                return;
            }

            order.status = statusMap[status];
            await order.save({ session });
            logger.info(`Order ${orderId} status updated to ${order.status} by user ${userId}`);

            if (order.status === 'Delivered') {
                const activationProductExists = await checkActivationProduct(order);
                const user = await User.findById(order.user).session(session);

                if (activationProductExists && !user.isActive) {
                    if (user.referredBy) {
                        logger.info(`Processing registration for referred user ${user.userId}`);
                        await processRegistration(user.referredBy, user.userId);

                        // Refresh user data after registration
                        await user.reload();
                    }
                }

                // Process commission only after registration (if applicable) is complete
                logger.info(`Processing commission for user ${user.userId}`);
                await processCommission(user, order.totalPoints);
            }

            logger.info(`Order ${orderId} processing completed.`);
        });

        session.endSession();
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle error appropriately
    }
});


The registration queue is in a waiting state and then stalled.
Redis is running.
Current status of jobs:

Waiting Jobs: 0
Active Jobs: 0
Completed Jobs: 0



When attempting to process a registration job, I see the following logs repeatedly:
Processing registration for referred user E6737BB306
Adding registration job for user E6737BB306
Job 1 is waiting

Is there anything blocking the registration queue from starting? Previously, the registration and commission queues worked fine when in separate sessions, but now the registration jobs are not starting when they're part of another queue.
